# Sizeof in function

Tags: c++

How do I get the size of bits of an Array from a function

```
int NumberOfElements(int Array[]);

int main()
{
    int Array[] = { 5,5,6,5,5 };
    std::cout << NumberOfElements(Array);
}
int NumberOfElements(int Array[]) {
    return sizeof(Array);
}
```

It's returning 4.
Result should be 20.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size

Answer (score 5):

Arrays decay into pointers when passed as arguments to functions etc.
The size 4 means that the pointer has that size. It does not tell you anything about the number of elements in the actual array.

You may want to use a `std::vector<int>` instead where the size is part of its interface:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> Array{ 5,5,6,5,5 };
    std::cout << NumberOfElements(Array);
}
int NumberOfElements(const std::vector<int>& Array) {
    return Array.size();
}
```

Comment: I thought 4 for the int type. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @ManojBanik It may be, but you are probably on a 32 bit machine and `int` and pointers may have the same size.